# Multiple parameter values logic

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a simple select and two parameters.

```
@first
@second

SELECT ProductID, ProductName, ProductType, ProductLevel
FROM ProductTable
```

When I execute the procedure if both parameters have no values then I need this part to be executed:

```
WHERE ProductType = 1 AND ProductLevel = 1
```

IF I have value of first parameter then :

```
WHERE ProductType = 2 AND ProductName LIKE  @first + '%'
```

IF I have value of second parameter then :

```
WHERE ProductType =3 AND ProductName LIKE  @second + '%'
```

Can someone help me to implement this logic and create valid stored procedure ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you right then you need the next 'WHERE' statement:

```
WHERE 
    (@first IS NULL AND @second IS NULL AND ProductType = 1 AND ProductLevel = 1)
    OR
    (@first is NOT NULL AND ProductType = 2 AND ProductName LIKE @first + '%')
    OR
    (@second is NOT NULL AND ProductType = 3 AND ProductName LIKE @second + '%')
```

Comment: When I declare parameter and execute procedure it still expects parameter who are not supplied if I do not write any values to them :/

Comment: What if you make your parameter as optional? @first VARCHAR(5) = NULL

Answer (score 1):

You Should try IN Format:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS products;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE products(
IN p_ProductName,
IN p_ProductType,
IN p_ProductLevel
)

BEGIN

   SELECT * FROM ProductTable WHERE ProductName LIKE '%p_ProductName%', ProductType LIKE '%p_ProductType%' , ProductLevel LIKE '%p_ProductLevel%';

END$$
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding Another way,

```
declare @whereCondition varchar(100)

if(@first='' && @second='')
 @whereCondition=ProductType = 1 AND ProductLevel = 1
else if(@first<>'' && @second='')
 @whereCondition=ProductType = 2 AND ProductName LIKE  @first + '%'
else if(@first='' && @second<>'')
 @whereCondition=ProductType =3 AND ProductName LIKE  @second + '%'

exec('SELECT ProductID, ProductName, ProductType, ProductLevel
FROM ProductTable where=@whereCondition')
```

if the logic seems bigger, we can achieve by this way.